# Watch and history logging the Login and Logout events of users in Linux

Tags: linux, login

I would like to maintains login and logout history of users in Linux.

That is, let me know if relevant system calls are used for login and logout events so that I can do it by system call hooking.

Also, if there is another way that my proprietary code(process or thread) can receive events of login and logout.

In addition, if there is already login/out history maintenance mechanism in Linux, please let me know where I can get the detail information.

Thank you.

Happy

Comment: Searching login history for particular users might help in part or in suplement to another method: http://serverfault.com/questions/305738/how-do-i-extract-login-history

Answer (score 6):

If the kernel's audit subsystem is enabled, you can enable the `pam_loginuid.so` PAM module, which will create a new "audit session" for each login (by writing to /proc/self/loginuid). This will be logged by auditd or systemd-journald.

But besides that there *aren't* any "login" system calls. Almost everything is done in user space (and a bit scattered around), except for the final credential switching (which is however also frequently done by daemons internally). There is no single "user has logged in" event, at least none that would be consistent across all Linux distributions.

However, all the involved components *do* already log heaps of information. For example, you can find a session log in `/var/log/wtmp` (read with the commands `who <file>` or `last`), and you can find several messages regarding each login in `/var/log/secure` or `/var/log/auth.log` or the systemd journal:

```
sshd[3037]: Authorized to grawity, krb5 principal grawity@NULLROUTE.EU.ORG (krb5_kuserok)
sshd[3037]: Accepted gssapi-with-mic for grawity from 2a00:1a28:1157:143::2 port 55350 ssh2
kernel: audit: type=1006 audit(1441862594.054:16701): pid=3037 uid=0 old-auid=4294967295 auid=1000 old-ses=4294967295 ses=14576 res=1
sshd[3037]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user grawity by (uid=0)
systemd-logind[1531]: New session 14576 of user grawity.
```

For monitoring this within your own program, there are several choices:

- If the target machines run systemd, you can monitor the D-Bus signals sent by systemd-logind (`SessionNew` and `SessionRemoved`). ConsoleKit has a similar interface.
- You can implement your own PAM module which sends notifications over IPC. It would be similar to the "session" stage of `pam_unix` (which currently just prints the above message to syslog).
- You can inotify-watch the "utmp" or "wtmp" files (the former at `(/var)/run/utmp` on Linux, the latter at `/var/log/wtmp`). Most login sessions are recorded there for viewing with `who` or `w`. (utmp holds the current state, whereas wtmp is an actual log.)
- You can use auditd, which will log both the kernel messages from `pam_loginuid` as well as various userspace messages from daemons.

Don't forget to distinguish between "interactive" logins (gdm, sshd, login), "service" logins (imap, ftp), and "batch" sessions (cron, systemd-user).

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Could you please advice in more detail about the last statement which is "Don't forget to distinguish between "interactive" logins (gdm, sshd, login), "service" logins (imap, ftp), and "batch" sessions (cron, systemd-user)."